Does it refer to the preceding noun or preparatory it?
And can I paraphrase the clause into 'so it can be easy to overeat it.' Is it grammatically correct? I think the second it is redundant.

Bread is surprisingly calorie-dense, even when it’s made from whole
grains, so it can be easy to overeat.


There's some ambiguity in your sentence, because the highlighted 'it' could be read as either referring back to the bread you are speaking about or, as you suggest, acting as a 'preparatory it', referring to situations where one might overeat.
Looking at it critically - on the one hand, it arguably makes more sense to consider it as the preparatory subject because it is slightly unusual to say "I overeat bread". 'Overeating' usually means consuming more food than the body needs in general, and while it might not be 'wrong' to say you overeat a specific food, it isn't common - we'd more likely say "I eat too much bread". On the other hand, however, without specifically saying "it can be easy to overeat bread" (or "overeat it"!) it could suggest the calorie density of bread makes one overeat food in general.
Personally, I'd reword and say:

Bread is surprisingly calorie-dense, even when it’s made from whole grains, so it can be easy to eat too much of it.

This uses a preparatory subject to refer to potential situations and uses a final 'it' to refer back to the bread. The 'it' I have struck out is unnecessary. It's not wrong, but removing it makes it read better. You can have too many 'it's.

I'm not sure there's a recognized transitive use of "overeat"
